# Question regarding Extreme Value Theory and finding the distribution of X(n)

Tags: self-study, distributions, extreme-value

Hello stats stack exchange, I have a question regarding Order Statistics and the asymptotic distribution of $X_n$ which is the rv for max($X_1$, $X_2$,...,$X_n$) where $X_i$ are from some distribution.

I was reading my past lecture notes, and came upon an example for finding the limit of as n tend toward infinity, the distribution for $X_n$ if $X_i$ are exponentially distributed with parameter 1.

$F_{X_n}(x)=(1-e^{-x})^n$ is the cdf of $X_n$

We let $z/n$ = $e^{-x}$

We get P($X_n$ $\le$ $logn - logz$)=$(1-z/n)^{n}$

So if we take the limit we get $e^{-z}$

I get up till this point, however the following is what I dont quite understand, the lecture notes say to subtract logn from $X_n$ to obtain a rv which converges in distribution, which means
limit as n goes to infinity $P(X_n-logn \le -logz)=e^{-z}$
But then it says "We put $x =-logz$, ie $z=e^{-x}$" and obtained:
$P(X_n-log n \le x) => exp(-exp(-x))$
why can we just say let $x=-logz$? didnt we already let $x=logn-logz$?

Thank you for reading, I just dont quite understand how this works, my guess is we are just letting z as a dummy variable? But still I would like some clarification, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance you found $$P(X_{(n)}\le \log n-\log z)=\left(1-\frac{z}{n}\right)^n\tag{1}\longrightarrow  e^{-z}$$

Then you are asked to substitute $x=-\log z$, so that $(1)$ becomes $$P(X_{(n)}-\log n\le x)=\left(1-\frac{e^{-x}}{n}\right)^n \longrightarrow \exp(-e^{-x})\tag{2}$$

Forget the $x$ you defined to get $(1)$ in the first place. The $x$ defined to get $(2)$ from $(1)$ is different from the previous $x$ (it is a dummy variable after all). That is all there is to it.

Comment: So its just a dummy variable, where if I were to be asked to find the extreme value distribution of another distribution, I can just define it so that 1 it doesn't depend on n, and 2 that is convenient to me?

Comment: Both $(1)$ and $(2)$ in this answer are equivalent extreme value distributions. In general, one often writes the limiting distribution of a random variable $X_n$ (say) in the form $Z=\frac{X_n-a_n}{b_n}$ for some suitable sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ so that $Z$ converges in law to a standard distribution.